# Need a specific URL RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new to setting up the .htaccess and I would appreciate some help in my problem.

If the user hits the following URL (original URL):

http://www.example.com/somepage/something

I want it to redirect to:

http://www.example.com/somepage

AND keep the original URL in the browser.

So far, I have the following:

```
RewriteRule ^somepage/(.*)$ /somepage [R=301]
```

But, it doesnt work.

How do I get this working?

**EDIT:**

Here is what my .htaccess file looks like right now:

```
# do not allow anyone else to read your .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
deny from all
</Files>

# forbid viewing of directories
Options All -Indexes

# hide this list of files from being seen when listing a directory
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

# disable the server signature- helps with preformance
ServerSignature Off

RewriteEngine On
#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^somepage/(.*)$ /somepage [R=301]
```

Comment: Rahul, you cannot redirect *and* keep the same URL in the browser. If you have a rule to handle requests to `/somepage`, then you can simply remove the `R=301`. Would also suggest replacing that with `L`, to indicate that it will not continue check rules if a match is found. **Edit:** Perhaps you'd like to share your `.htaccess` file so we can see everything in context?

Comment: @MikeAnthony I have added the .htaccess file in the question above. I have asked this qiestion here on SO because my friend suggested that idea of showing one URL while there is another URL active behind the scenes, but he couldnt recollect that RewriteRule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule is the problem:

```
RewriteRule ^somepage/(.*)$ /somepage [R=301]
```

for two reasons:

1. Since you don't want URL to change you must not use `R=301` flag in this rule.
2. Bigger problem is that your regex `^somepage/(.*)$` will also also match `/somepage/` and you needed to match `/somepage/something`.

To fix this issue have your full .htaccess like this:

```
# do not allow anyone else to read your .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
deny from all
</Files>

# forbid viewing of directories
Options All -Indexes

# hide this list of files from being seen when listing a directory
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

# disable the server signature- helps with preformance
ServerSignature Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+) $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, that didnt work. I am getting `500 Internal Server Error` when I hit the original URL. In my project, `somepage` is actually `cord-blood-basics`, so I tried both `cord-blood-basics` and `cord\-blood\-basics` in the regex, but that also didnt work. I also tried without the `^` in the begining and that didnt work either.

Comment: `somepage` is not a real directory, it is a HTML file. `something` is the button in the accordian of this HTML page which I am trying to click programmatically when this URL is hit. I know this might sound weird to you, but you will get the context better if you refer [this question that I posted earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497024/routing-the-user-friendly-url-to-the-page-with-an-accordian). And, this is the only .htaccess file in my project.

Comment: In `xampp\apache\logs\error.log`, this is what I am getting after hitting that URL: `[Fri Feb 13 21:25:18.260038 2015] [core:error] [pid 6176:tid 1692] [client 127.0.0.1:55869] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: Now it is giving me a 404 error. When I looked into the Network tab of the dev tools, I see that it is looking for file `something` of type HTML. No error in the Apache error log.

Comment: That URL works. What I am doing when that URL is hit is programatically clicking a default button in the accordian and using `history.pushState()` so that the URL looks like `http://domain.com/somepage/something`, where `something` = ID of the button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70870/discussion-between-rahul-desai-and-anubhava).

Comment: Most of my answer was included in your question as well. If your question is about `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]` then it is checking existence of `.html` file. `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` is Apache property of your web root and `$1` is the value captured from matching group #1 in `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Can you please help me with [this follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466873/rewriterule-causing-301-redirect)? Its on the same lines.