# Link to section within Accordion using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have **2** pages. `page1.html` contains a series of links & `page2.html` has an Accordion.

**My Question:**
Is it possible to link directly to a section in the Accordion? So, if I wanted to visit 'Celtic', how do I create a link that **a)** opens correct Accordion tab **b)** anchors down to celtic id.

Here's my current code for `page2.html`: http://jsfiddle.net/7k9s1pg7/

**HTML:**

```
<dl class="accordion">

<dt><a href="" class="container heading">Soccer</a></dt>
<dd id="soccer">
  <div id="manutd">

    <p>Man Utd</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

  </div>  

  <div id="celtic">

    <p>Celtic</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

  </div>
</dd>

<dt><a href="" class="container heading">Formula 1</a></dt>
<dd id="formula1">
  <div id="lewishamilton">

    <p>Lewis Hamilton</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

  </div>  

  <div id="michaelschumacher">

    <p>Michael Schumacher</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

  </div>
</dd>
</dl>
```

**Javascript:**

```
(function($) {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    var allLinks = $('a.heading');
    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();

        allLinks.removeClass('active');

        if ($(this).parent().next().is(":visible")) return false;
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();

        $(this).addClass('active');

        return false;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anchors in `page1` links: `page2.html#lewishamilton` and add to your JS code

```
var hash = location.hash;
if (hash) {
    var el = $(hash);
    el.parent().slideDown();
    el.parent().prev().find('a').addClass('active');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7k9s1pg7/2/

Comment: Many thanks for both taking the time to read my question and your answer. This is excellent. Can you explain what my default should be. `var hash = location.hash`?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk: yes, `location.hash` returns everything what is in URL after `#` including the hash sign. I updated my code (put there `location.hash` instead of 'lewishamilton' and updated `$(hash)`) - removed '#' from there.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation. I'm just testing it in my current site and will report back ASAP with how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: Back :-)
Is there an obvious reason why this fails http://jsfiddle.net/7k9s1pg7/3/ when this works http://jsfiddle.net/7k9s1pg7/4/?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk: you changed HTML markup, use `closest` instead of `parent`: http://jsfiddle.net/7k9s1pg7/5/

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, I don't think `location.hash` is working for me :(

Comment: I have accepted the answer but I don't know why the `location.hash` doesn't work for me. When I replace with `lewishamilton` it works great, but take that out and add it to the URL, and it fails :(

Comment: My apologies. I didn't see the change reflected in http://jsfiddle.net/7k9s1pg7/5/ Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced a same problem recently. I fixed it by setting up the RewriteRule in .htaccess instead of playing with the frontend code.

I did this because my requirement was to have a user-friendly URL for a better UX. The other option is to go for `#` (`location.hash`).

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500941/need-a-specific-url-rewriterule-in-htaccess).

My idea was to hit a URL that looks user-friendly. Something like:

http://www.example.com/somepage/something

Where `somepage` is the page with the accordian and `something` is the ID of the button inside a section of the accordian.

In `somepage`, you will need to write code to read the `something` from the URL on `onload` by using `window.location.pathname` and then programatically click the `something` button.

Note that this fixes your accordian problem and also gives a good UX by rendering a user-friendly URL.